# I want to insert in a vector multiple values in a location

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

When I create a vector , let's say size of 5 , elements are 1,2,3,4,5 and I want to add at the location( for example index 2) the numbers 200 and 300 , the vector should look like 1 ,2 ,200,300,3,4,5.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int v[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int n = sizeof(v)/sizeof(int);
    int location,element;
    printf("Enter location:");
    scanf("%d",&location);
    printf("Enter element:");
    scanf("%d",&element);
    for(int i = n - 1; i >= location;i--){
        v[i + 1] = v[i];
    }
    v[location] = element;
    for(int i = 0; i <= n;i++){
        printf("%d ",v[i]);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please do not post images, please paste the code into the question, this allows us to copy it and paste into our own tools. Also please say what problem you are having

Comment: Be aware that if you dont do as I advise your question will get closed very soon

Comment: I want for example to put the location 0 , and for example values 200 and 300 and to have a vector which will be +2 values bigger

Comment: ok, sir , I will update the question.

Comment: put the code in the question, put the question in the question

Comment: `#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int v[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int n = sizeof(v)/sizeof(int);
    int location,element;
    printf("Enter location:");scanf("%d",&location);printf("Enter element:");scanf("%d",&element);
    for(int i = n - 1; i >= location;i--){
        v[i + 1] = v[i];
    }
    v[location] = element;
    for(int i = 0; i <= n;i++){
        printf("%d ",v[i]);
    }
}

Comment: I wrote the code in the questions

Comment: BTW it would not be me closing it, there are others on SO who will quickly close questions like this, thats why I warned you.

Comment: Nope, click the 'edit' button and put the code in the question, at the same time put the question in the question

Comment: ok ,10 minutes , I am having a really bad time to figure out how to do this

Comment: Hi, the code is has been written , I want to insert multiple values in a location in a vector

Comment: In your code I find no attempt to ask for multiple values -- let be inserting multiple elements. Show your efforts.

Comment: `int v[100] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};` make that size `100`, you'll be able to insert up to hundred elements including the ones in initialisation.

Comment: When `i == n - 1` `v[i + 1]` is out of bounds BTW.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop like this

```
for(;;){
  int location,element;
  printf("Enter location:");

  scanf("%d",&location);

  if(location == -1)
     break;
  printf("Enter element:"); 
  scanf("%d",&element);
  for(int i = n - 1; i >= location;i--){
    v[i + 1] = v[i];
  }
  v[location] = element;
}
```

BUT you code is severely broken, you are adding to a vector thats of fixed size. you cannot do that

In this code

```
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= location; i--) {
        v[i + 1] = v[i];
    }
```

n is the count of number of elements, so on the first loop you do

```
        v[n] = v[n-1]
```

ie

```
       v[7] = v[6]
```

well v[7] is off the end of the array (array indexes are 0 to 6) Thats very bad

Comment: The loop requirement is for the elements entered to be contiguous starting _from_ location, your solution requires the location to be entered each time.

Comment: @Clifford well I leave that as an exercise for OP :-) Took me a lot of work just to get OP to post any code

Comment: What do you mean by 'your solution requires the location to be entered each time'?

Comment: First of all , do I need to create another dynamically allocated vector or what?

Comment: @VladGuzun depends on what you want , you could keep a fixed size array and just discard the elements that dont fit anymore, ie when you insert at the start delete the last entry. Or you can make a bigger array. In that case you should malloc the initial one too so that you code is the same for the first array and the subsequent ones

Answer (score 0):

You declared a fixed size array

```
int v[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

You can not enlarge it.

Thus this loop

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n;i++){
    printf("%d ",v[i]);
}
```

invokes undefined behavior due to using the index with the value `n` that is outside the valid range of indices `[0, n)` for the source array.

You need to allocate the array dynamically and when you are going to add one more element you will need to reallocate the array.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    size_t n = 7;

    int *v = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );
    memcpy( v, ( int [7] ){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, n * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", v[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t location = 0;

    printf( "Enter location: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &location );

    if ( n < location ) location = n;

    int element = 0;

    printf( "Enter element: " );
    scanf( "%d",&element );

    int *tmp = realloc( v, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );
    
    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        v = tmp;

        memmove( v + location + 1, v + location, ( n - location ) * sizeof( int ) );
        v[location] = element;
        ++n;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", v[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    free( v );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Enter location: 2
Enter element: 200
1 2 200 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: can I just leave the first vector as it is ,and to make a second vector dynamically ?

Comment: @VladGuzun Yes , you can. Wait a minute I will provide a solution.

Comment: When I create a vector , let's say size of 5 , elements are 1,2,3,4,5 and I want to add at the location( for example index 2) the numbers 200 and 300 , the vector should look like 1 ,2 ,200,300,3,4,5. Can you help me with the code :(

Comment: @VladGuzun See my updated post.

Comment: but what if I want to put 2 numbers ,instead of 1

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Enter location: 2
Enter elements: 200 ,300
1 2 200 300 3 4 5 6 7

Comment: @VladGuzun You need to allocate more memory as for example int *tmp = realloc( v, ( n + 2 ) * sizeof( int ) ); and use memmove( v + location + 2, v + location, ( n - location ) * sizeof( int ) ); If course n shall be increased like n += 2;